# DocumentViewer GoToPage() Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a little a problem with the WPF DocumentViewer.
I'm displaying an XPS file using the DocumentViewer.
I want to navigate the XPS document to a certain Page but it navigates to the wrong page number during the initializing of the window.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Window : Window
{
    private string _XPSpath;

    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _XPSPath = @"C:\TestFolder\TestDocument.xps";
        MyDocViewer.Document = new XpsDocument(_XPSpath, FileAccess.Read).GetFixedDocumentSequence();

        DocViewer.GoToPage(100); // Navigates to wrong page !!!!!!!!!            
    }

    private void GoToPageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DocViewer.GoToPage(100); //this one is ok.
    }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: its 92 and the page wasn't displayed correctly the page border is in the middle of the viewer!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @JMK: i think he is telling that navigation is not happening while initializing the window, but it navigates properly when button was clicked.correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Sorry I understand that now

Comment: This case isnt only while  initializing the window,but if you try to display another FixedDocumentSequence using the same viewer and command it to navigate to a page(immediatly) you will face this issue

Comment: @صلاحابوغليون: i think the problem is with calling ".GetFixedDocumentSequence()".